# How to show power BI report in local ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, powerbi, dashboard

Hi is there a way to show power BI reports without embedded or using Azure in an ASP .NET MVC Project? Is for a local project, I already have the report done but most of the tutorials I have found always embedded it or use an SDK that later needs to payed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Power BI elements can be rendered only by Power BI (either Power BI Service in the cloud or Power BI Report Server on premise). Your only option to do this is to publish the report to one of these two and then to embed it in your web application.

Depending on the authentication type and where the report is hosted, there are different ways to embed it. Here are some of them:

- [Embed a report in a secure portal or website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-embed-secure)
- [Embed a Power BI Report Server report using an iFrame in SharePoint Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/quickstart-embed)
- [Tutorial: Embed Power BI content using a sample embed for your customers' application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core)
- [Tutorial: Embed Power BI content using a sample embed for your organization application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-your-organization?tabs=net-core)